# How to get Bitmap image from OI file manager path?

Tags: android

My application requires an image to be selected from gallery.

I start activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

It will prompt to select from gallery or OI file manager

For the OI file manager, I get the path from Uri as follow:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
```

Now how do I get Bitmap image from the filemanagerstring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)`;

Look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String))

Comment: Even though this is old. `BitmapFactory` doesn't use braces as far as I know, the right syntax would be `BitmapFactory.decode...` +1